# Apache Jmeter - The CSRF tokens do not match

Tags: apache, jmeter, token, csrf

I have recorded basic Apache Jmeter scenario with html login form which uses csrf tokens.

Sample token recorded by application looks as follows:

```
<input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="IjU5NzBhMmI3ODNjZGVjMGUwYmI2YTU4ZjRkMTk0MjI0MTg3OTJlNDAi.C8ecSA.PkvdB0aM2M0rfhSLcb_ktyeInfs">
```

Using Apache Jmeter Post Processor (REGEX) I am extracting value with the following expression:

```
input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="(.+?)"
```

Result is a success and value is assigned to CSRF_VALUE variable.

In the next step I am sending the token with login information to website, post data looks as follows:

```
username=username&password=password&csrf_token=IjU5NzBhMmI3ODNjZGVjMGUwYmI2YTU4ZjRkMTk0MjI0MTg3OTJlNDAi.C8ecSA.PkvdB0aM2M0rfhSLcb_ktyeInfs&submit=Zaloguj+si%C4%99
```

However website returns error that csrf tokens do not match. The only thing changed between recorded scenario and modified is extraction and placing csrf token in the follow up request. Every time I replay this scenario I check results and they show that **csrf token received** == **csrf token sent**. But login fails with the same error - csrf tokens do not match.

So far I can't get what is wrong, very simple scenario and yet there is a problem. I am using apache jmeter 3.1.

Comment: REALLY? I'm just dealing with the same problem since yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend checking other than request body parts, i.e.

- your application may expect CSRF token to be in a request header, in that case you will need to add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send the relevant header
- your application may expect a Cookie with the CSRF token value. In that case you will need to handle it using [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
- it might be a problem with HTML encoding and decoding, i.e. extracted token value may have some extra characters due to escaping entities which are not allowed in HTML. In that case you will need to use [JMeter Functions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like [__unescapeHtml()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__unescapeHtml) to normalize the token value

Carefully inspect requests and responses using developer tools in browser and JMeter's [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener, most likely the reason is listed above.

Just in case check out [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) guide.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it's been a while since I did http testing. I followed through your advice and found the missing part.

Comment: So what was the missing part?